# Report file preview popup window is different to the actual report design

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2013

This is the design of my report:

[image]

But when I click a button on runtime to preview the report that is about to be saved as PDF file it looks very different!

[image]

However when I download the file as PDF it looks just the way I designed it:

[image]

How do I fix the preview design?

Answer (score 2):

White-space is very finicky in SSRS and you are experiencing this different behavior because you are using two different renderers and they are just flat out behaving a bit different.  Looking at your design screen, it appears that you have just floating textboxes and white-space underneath between the last content and the footer.  HTML rendering can be tricked into rendering that white-space before the footer by placing empty content (textbox or rectangle) in that space like so:

[image]

**Red box**: I would try inserting a blank rectangle off to the side, but the whole height, first.

**Blue box**: The next option would be to wrap the whole page contents into a rectangle.

It's actually a bit funny because most people are stuck trying to get rid of white-space in their HTML rendered report and you actually have the opposite issue here.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'll keep you updated. I'm very new to SSRS. Btw, why are there little boxes in that HTML version? It's taking up space that ruined the design

Comment: I also found out that it looks more accurate in Internet Explorer. And only in Chrome those little boxes appear. I tested it in Firefox, IE, and Chrome

Comment: I've seen lots of differences between Chrome/Firefox and IE for various reports.  I don't know what is causing the specific boxes in this case though.  I do find that IE works the best though since it's the native browser for MS.

Comment: I somehow solved the "Chrome little box" issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45454067/tiny-boxes-appear-when-rendering-ssrs-reports-in-html-viewed-from-chrome?noredirect=1#comment77873976_45454067