# Tiny boxes appear when rendering SSRS reports in HTML viewed from Chrome

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2013

This this the current design of my report:

[image]

When I run it on different browser except for Chrome, it's looks almost ok (I have no idea why the HTML render is different from the expected result):

[image]

But in Chrome, it's a different story. Tiny boxes appear out of nowhere. How do I get rid of it?:

[image]

Comment: would love to see a solution to this issue. fingers crossed mate.

Comment: Woah! You're experiencing it too?! Actually I have made a tweak that somehow solved it.

Comment: I'm listening ;)

Comment: see my answer in a while

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the boxes are generated upon loading the page. It creates a gif image named "Blank.gif" here is the complete code when I entered 'Inspect Element':

```
<img src="/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?Culture=1033&amp;CultureOverrides=True&amp;UICulture=1033&amp;UICultureOverrides=True&amp;ReportStack=1&amp;ControlID=712a96453ecc4eb89b71439a5477d6c6&amp;Mode=true&amp;OpType=ReportImage&amp;ResourceStreamID=Blank.gif"/>
```

I solved it by just creating a CSS style that finds img elements in the body that matches the source of that image element with "Blank.gif" and then hides it.

Here is my solution:

```
<style>
        body:nth-of-type(1) img[src*="Blank.gif"]
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Could you explain where you added this please? was it inside the report file "view code" window? or somewhere else. Having more context would help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'd used lines in the report to create custom-shaped tables. Those lines were the problem.

I created my own table using rectangles instead of lines. And there are no more empty images.